# Datatables in Bootstrap modal width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

In my modal I am trying to put Datatables in there, the problem I'm having is that the width is incorrect, it should be the width of the modal but it is actually like this

[image]

**My jQuery calling the Datatables**

```
function getValidTags(){
      var ruleID = $('.ruleID').val();

      var table = $('.valid-tags').DataTable({
      "ajax": {
          "url": "/ajax/getValidTags.php",
          "type": "POST",
          "data": {
            ruleID: ruleID
          },
      },
      "columnDefs": [{
         "targets": 2,
         "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
            return '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">Manage</button> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
         }
      }]        
  });   
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<!-- Modal where you will be able to add new rule -->
<div class="modal fade validation-list-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="LargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-wide">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header modal-header-custom">
            <input class="ruleID" type="hidden"></input>     
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title modal-title-main">Create New Rule</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="topBar">                       
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="validTags inputTextStyling">
                </div>
            </div>
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed valid-tags">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Tag Name</th>
                            <th>Autofixes</th>
                            <th>Manage</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="validTagsTable">
                    </tbody>                    
                </table>                           
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveValidTags">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can we see your html ?

Comment: @Kypaz Just added it now.

Comment: Did you have style="width:100%;"  for your <table> html element ?

Comment: @FrançoisDupont thanks this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters try adding following class to your table element

```
.dataTableLayout {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

It would be good if you could make a **fiddle** of your code with dummy data for solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks Prakash & Francois, didn't think this would be the problem but turns out it was.

Comment: I will accept it as the answer, I have to wait 10 minutes first.

Answer (score 13):

I find this more appropriate solution,

First make your table width 100%
like this:

```
<table width="100%" id="datatable"></table>
```

then initialize your table

```
$('#datatable').DataTable();
```

and this this

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @josemaria if you find this helpful. :)

Answer (score 4):

I dont think the accepted answer is *the* correct answer. There should be no need at all for altering the CSS. It could cause unexpected issues elsewhere. The problem is, that the container (the modal) not is fully established at the time the dataTable is rendered. Look at [**`columns.adjust()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
     this.api().columns.adjust()
  }
  ...
})
```

or

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  table.columns.adjust()
})
```

Comment: I used the second option (.on('shown.bs.modal') and it works like a charm. Be sure to use the new datatables api to reference the table object. .DataTable iso .dataTable

Answer (score 0):

I just added table inside div, assigned width:100%; overflow-x:auto to that div and it worked.